# Task.Factory.StartNew ignores Task.WaitAll

Tags: c#, task

I have some problems with Task.Factory.StartNew and Task.WaitAll. The tasks do start as they should but it looks like it just ignores the Task.WaitAll, because after clicking my button (it's the event this code is in) the MessageBox already popsup.

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
        if (plugin.UseProxy)
        {
            foreach (var item in combo)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    // Some code
                }).ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    tasks.Add(t);
                    pbProgress.Value++;

                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var item in combo)
            {
                Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    // Some code
                }).ContinueWith((t) =>
                {
                    tasks.Add(t);
                    pbProgress.Value++;

                }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            }
        }

        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
        MessageBox.Show("Hello");
```

Comment: Because your `tasks` list is empty at the moment you executing `Task.WaitAll`

Answer (score 3):

You only add the Tasks to your List when they finish. `ContinueWith` executes when the task is done. So `Task.WaitAll` is waiting an empty list of Tasks.

So you can do this:

```
Task task = Task.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Some code
}).ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    pbProgress.Value++;
}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

tasks.Add(task);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `tasks` list only get the items added to it once the thread started via the `StartNew` finishes. The problem you are having is you are hitting the `Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());` before the items are added to the collection. You need to add the items to the collection in the thread that is creating them, not in the continue with,

```
var newTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
{
    // Some code
});
tasks.Add(newTask);
newTask.ContinueWith((t) =>
{
    pbProgress.Value++;

}, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

However your code has other problems too. You never pass in a `TaskSchedueller` to the factory, if you don't you can [easily accidentally start your thread on the UI thread](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html). Also I assume this code is running on the UI thread, your `Task.WaitAll` will block the UI thread. This can lead to deadlocks if one of those `StartNew` threads ended up on a UI thread.

Comment: I see thanks. How can I avoid the deadlocks with Task.WaitAll?

Comment: new Thread(() =>
            {
                Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
                MessageBox.Show("Hello");
            }); I'm doing this,, and my UI doesnt freeze anymore. But now my MessageBox doesnt pop up anymore xD

Comment: By using async/await and `Tasks.WhenAll`. Go read a basic async/await tutorial.